# StencilJS using component in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, stenciljs

I want to use a component created using StencilJS in a regular basic HTML file. I followed these steps:

I have created a stencil component to create the basic my-component example:

```
npm init stencil
```

I want to use this component in an HTML file, so I ran

```
npm run build
```

I then created an html project with the following structure:

[image]

And then I moved the files from the dist folder into the script folder. And I added script tag in the head of my html file that references the component.js file like this:

```
<script src="script/{component_name}/{component_name}.js"></script>
```

And I used the component in the html like this:

```
<my-component first="Stencil" last="'Don't call me a framework' JS"></my-component>
```

But my component isn't being rendered. I get an error involving a esm.js file. Can someone help me with this process of compiling my stencil component to be using in a basic HTML project?

Answer (score 7):

Stencil bundles your dist into modules and lazy-loads only the required code based on the components you are actually using in your HTML. So you should serve the whole `dist` folder along with your website.

The recommended way is to have the following two script tags in your html file:

```html
<script type="module" src="/dist/[namespace]/[namespace].esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="/dist/[namespace]/[namespace].js"></script>
```

(where `[namespace]` is whatever is set in your `stencil.config.ts`)

This will instruct browsers who support ES Modules to use the esm bundle, and other browsers will use the ES5 (cjs) bundle.

If `my-component` is the only component that you're using from your library, then only that code will be lazy-loaded by your page. Stencil knows about component interdependencies and how to lazy-load them accordingly.

---

There is a new experimental output target (called `custom-elements-bundle`) that allows you to bundle everything into one js file, which will simplify distribution in some cases. <strike>It's only available with the new refactored compiler (which is available using the `--next` flag, after installing `@stencil/core@next`)</strike> (Stencil 2 has been out for a while now).

Comment: Hello mate! I'm checking but nomodule path is wrong, do you know why?

Comment: No I don't know. I just looked at https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cdn and it's still the same paths.

Comment: Oh in my case that script doesn't exist because es5 was disabled by default since Stencil 2.0, thanks! https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#opt-in-for-es5-and-systemjs-builds